# text alignment in center

Tags: html, css

This is my text css but text is not coming in center. Can please explain me why its not coming in center.

```
.button {
            background-color: #338DFF;
            border: none;
            width : 15px;
            height : 15px;
            color: white;
            border-style: solid;
            line-height: 2px;
            border-color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

Comment: it is the `padding` property

Comment: Have you tried text-align: center !important;

Comment: When working CSS issues it is often a good practice to start with "what can/do I need to remove" - simpler is sometimes better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is centered the problem is the width as you can see you have only 15 px to display the text and the text is to large that overflows the area and it looks not centered

```css
.button {
            background-color: #338DFF;
            border: none;
            /*width : 15px; This is setting a small area for the text*/
            height : 15px;
            color: white;
            border-style: solid;
            line-height: 2px;
            border-color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<button class="button">test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 2):

Remove `width` that's it

```css
.button {
            background-color: #338DFF;
            border: none;
            height : 15px;
            color: white;
            border-style: solid;
            line-height: 2px;
            border-color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            
        }
```

```html
<button class="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because of `padding` and `height` property. Remove them and give required height and width.

```css
.button {
            background-color: #338DFF;
            border: none;
            width : 75px;
            height : 20px;
            color: white;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: white;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<div class="button"> button </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
.button {
            background-color: #338DFF;
            border: none;
            width : 75px;
            height : 20px;
            color: white;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: white;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            vertical-align: middle;/*Added This**/
        }
```

```html
<div class="button"> button </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving height, width, line-height and padding padding. Padding with height and width sometime increase the size of the element. 
For your case just remove width, text will be central aligned.